# Turn off wallpaper-tinting from the command line

Tags: command-line, system-settings

Anyone know of a command to disable wallpaper tinting? That is, instead of clicking the checkbox in System Preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is controlled via the `AppleReduceDesktopTinting` global setting:

```
defaults write -g AppleReduceDesktopTinting -bool yes
```

---

A helpful tip for finding these is to dump everything and use `diff` to see what changed:

1. `defaults read > before`
2. [Change the setting]
3. `defaults read > after`
4. `diff before after`

There will likely be a lot of noise, but you should be able to sift through and find the one you're looking for!